# Is there any way to detect if an Android phone supports Voicemail integration in the call log?

Tags: android, voicemail

My app is using [VoicemailContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/VoicemailContract.html) functionality that's available in API 14 and higher to insert voicemail messages into the phone's call log. However, some phones seem to have that functionality disabled, even in API versions higher thatn 14. Samsung Galaxy Note 2 is a perfect example of this. So, when the new VM message is inserted into the database, it won't show up in the call log (but this works perfectly on most other phones). So, it seems that Samsung disabled that functionality on that phone somehow, and I'd like to be able to detect that at runtime so that I can hide that option in my app's settings if it isn't available.

Comment: Is it possible to just add a dummy message and check call log for existence of that message once?

Comment: I think that it's just the phone app (which is where the coll log is) that's affected. But you're absolutely right -- they might have disabled the whole Voicemail content provider. Let me try your idea, and see what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried checking the status?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/VoicemailContract.Status.html

Vendors can really implement almost anything they want on their phones (which makes android development very annoying) however I think the status should be set to something that is "not okay" on phones that will ignore your api calls.